# Most decent way to multiply/divide array values by $var in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Having an array of the type:

```
$arr = array(23,4,13,50,231,532,3);

$factor = 0.4;
```

I need to produce a new array where all values of `$arr` are multiplied/divided by `$factor`. I'm aware of `foreach` method. Just thought, there must be a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PHP 5.3 and higher:

```
$arr = array(23,4,13,50,231,532,3);

$arr_mod = array_map( function($val) { return $val * 0.4; }, $arr);
```

To pass in the factor dynamically, do:

```
$arr_mod = array_map( 
  function($val, $factor) { return $val * $factor; }, 
  $arr,
  array_fill(0, count($arr), 0.4)
);
```

as [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) say:

> The number of parameters that the callback function accepts should match the number of arrays passed to the `array_map()`.

It does not make too much sense in this simple example, but it enables you to define the callback independently somewhere else, without any hard-coded values.

The callback will receive the corresponding values from each array you pass to `array_map()` as arguments, so it's even thinkable to apply a different factor to every value in `$arr`.

Comment: Correction: it should be php 5.3 or higher instead of just php 5 or higher. Anonymous functions was added in php 5.3, not 5

Comment: what about 5.2? My client's hosting is running 5.2.5

Comment: @Zlatev: Declare the "multiply" function outside of the `array_map()` call and pass in a string of the function name instead of a function declaration. Use in conjunction with the second variant shown, or hard-code the factor of 0.4.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function to apply a callback function (which does the multiplication) to each array element:

```
function multiply($n) {
        $factor = 0.4;
        return($n * $factor);
}

$arr = array_map("multiply", $arr);
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/oqmsV)

Answer (score 2):

Note there are true lambadas after 5.3 
pre 5.3 you could use array_map as suggested (probably my first choice) or array_walk and pass by ref

```
array_walk($arr, create_function('&$val', '$val = $val * 0.4;'));
```

Comment: This is way more efficient than creating an array copy.I wonder why this is not the selected answer...

Answer (score 1):

To pass the factor dynamically and with a concise syntax you can use the following in more recent (>5.3.0, I think) versions of PHP:

```
$arr = array(23,4,13,50,231,532,3);
$factor = 0.5;

$arr_mod = array_map(
              function($val) use ($factor) { return $val * $factor; }, 
              $arr
           );
```